# How to provide attribute value in the template .erb file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

How to provide attribute value in a template .erb file

```
qradar_logs/
├── Berksfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── attributes
│   └── default.rb
├── chefignore
├── files
│   └── default
│       └── default
├── metadata.rb
├── recipes
│   └── default.rb
├── spec
│   ├── spec_helper.rb
│   └── unit
│       └── recipes
│           └── default_spec.rb
├── templates
│   └── rsyslog.conf.erb
└── test
    └── integration
        └── default
           └── default_test.rb

11 directories, 12 files
```

In `attribute.rb` file, I have the following contents:

```
default['logs']['hostname'] = "169.67.89.72:514"
```

In my recipe, I provided the following:

```
hostname = node['logs']['hostname']
```

In my templates `rsyslog.conf` file, I would like to use this value based on the value changed in `attributes` file.

I tried giving:

```
<%= "#{hostname}" %>
```

It errors out as:

```
FATAL: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError: undefined local variable or method `hostname'
```

How can I access the attributes defined in attribute file in `template.erb` file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few things. First you should use the `variables` property in your `template` resource to expose the data to the template:

```
template '/whatever' do
  # ...
  variables hostname: node['logs']['hostname']
end
```

Then you need to use Erb formatting, which you kind of did but not really:

```
<%= @hostname %>
```

The variable name matches the key you used with `variables`.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you. Saved a lot of time and efforts